# Passing parameters to an SVG file from CSS?

Tags: css, svg

Is there a way pass some data to a svg file when it's being used as background image. For example with something like this:

```
background-image:url("mysvg.svg?myparam=red")
```

and in `mysvg.svg` receive `red` from `myparam` parameter?

I've seen [Parameter Variables in SVG](https://dev.w3.org/SVG/modules/ref/master/SVGRefPrimer.html) but it seems require use of `<object>` in html, so just adding into svg

```
<defs>
  <ref id="myparam" param="myparam" default="blue"/>
</defs>
<rect x="5" y="5" width="100" height="30" rx="15" ry="15" fill="url(#myparam)" />
```

doesn't work and I'm trying to avoid use any kind of inline-html inside CSS if all possible.

Comment: I *believe* (but am not certain) if you give the `<img>` a reference (class, id) then the CSS can update some of the SVG properties in the CSS markup, [see here for more](https://css-tricks.com/svg-properties-and-css/).

Comment: @Martin It will only work if svg used within HTML, not within CSS...hens the dilemma...

Comment: please try `background-image: url(https://assets.codepen.io/222579/cat.svg#redcat)` and let me know if this is what you need

Comment: @enxaneta and how do you change the color to let's say `#123456` without hard code it into svg itself?

Comment: The svg file I'm using is prepared just for red and black.  Take a look to the file. I have the cat shape and then I use the cat once filled red and once filled black `#redcat` is targeting  the one filled red. In the css `svg > svg:not(:target) {display: none;}`

Comment: Yeah, I think you misunderstood the question...your svg colors are static, I'm looking for a way pass custom colors/data to svg